# Changing appearance of NSPopover?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopover

I'd like to make a NSPopover similar to this one:

[image: screenshot]

So I'd like to override the drawing.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything in the Apple documentation.
However, I did find the following private class using class dump:

```
@interface NSPopoverFrame : NSView
{
    const void *_themeX;
    long long _popoverAppearance;
    NSImage *_dragImage;
    unsigned long long _anchorEdge;
    struct CGSize _anchorSize;
    CDStruct_3c058996 _contentInset;
    struct CGPoint _anchorPoint;
    unsigned long long _previousAnchorEdge;
    struct CGPoint _previousAnchorPoint;
    unsigned int _windowFilter;
    struct {
        unsigned int useDragWindowAppearance:1;
        unsigned int hasActiveShadow:1;
        unsigned int hasShadow:1;
        unsigned int invalidateShadow:1;
        unsigned int hasWindowBackgroundBlur:1;
        unsigned int shouldBlurBackground:1;
        unsigned int shouldInsetForAnchor:1;
        unsigned int doingSolidFillHack:1;
    } _flags;
}

+ (struct CGRect)contentRectForFrameRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 styleMask:(unsigned long long)arg2;
+ (struct CGRect)frameRectForContentRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 styleMask:(unsigned long long)arg2;
+ (struct CGRect)contentRectForFrameRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 appearance:(long long)arg2 anchorSize:(struct CGSize)arg3 contentInset:(CDStruct_3c058996)arg4;
+ (struct CGRect)frameRectForContentRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 appearance:(long long)arg2 anchorSize:(struct CGSize)arg3 contentInset:(CDStruct_3c058996)arg4;
@property struct CGPoint anchorPoint; // @synthesize anchorPoint=_anchorPoint;
@property long long popoverAppearance; // @synthesize popoverAppearance=_popoverAppearance;
@property CDStruct_3c058996 contentInset; // @synthesize contentInset=_contentInset;
@property struct CGSize anchorSize; // @synthesize anchorSize=_anchorSize;
@property unsigned long long anchorEdge; // @synthesize anchorEdge=_anchorEdge;
- (struct CGRect)titlebarRect;
- (BOOL)_hasActiveDragTypes;
- (void)draggingEnded:(id)arg1;
- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id)arg1;
- (void)draggingExited:(id)arg1;
- (unsigned long long)draggingEntered:(id)arg1;
- (void)_markAnchorRectAsNeedingDisplay;
- (void)setFrameSize:(struct CGSize)arg1;
- (BOOL)_isBorderView;
- (void)_drawFrameShadowAndFlushContext:(id)arg1;
- (void)tileAndSetWindowShape:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)shapeWindow;
- (void)_setFrameNeedsDisplay:(BOOL)arg1;
- (id)opaqueAncestor;
- (BOOL)isOpaque;
- (struct CGRect)dragRectForFrameRect:(struct CGRect)arg1;
- (void)_resetDragMargins;
- (void)_clearDragMargins;
- (double)_distanceFromToolbarBaseToTitlebar;
- (void)_hideToolbarWithAnimation:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)_showToolbarWithAnimation:(BOOL)arg1;
- (BOOL)_toolbarIsManagedByExternalWindow;
- (BOOL)_toolbarIsHidden;
- (BOOL)_toolbarIsShown;
- (BOOL)_toolbarIsInTransition;
- (BOOL)_canHaveToolbar;
- (id)zoomButton;
- (id)minimizeButton;
- (id)closeButton;
- (unsigned long long)styleMask;
- (id)title;
- (void)_windowChangedKeyState;
- (void)drawRect:(struct CGRect)arg1;
- (struct CGPoint)_adjustedForBoundsAnchorPoint:(struct CGPoint)arg1 anchorEdge:(unsigned long long)arg2;
- (id)_getPopoverIfAvailable;
- (void)drawBackgroundInRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 ofView:(id)arg2 anchorEdge:(unsigned long long)arg3 anchorPoint:(struct CGPoint)arg4;
- (void)_drawHUDPopoverAppearanceInRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 anchorEdge:(unsigned long long)arg2 anchorPoint:(struct CGPoint)arg3;
- (void)_drawMinimalPopoverAppearanceInRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 anchorEdge:(unsigned long long)arg2 anchorPoint:(struct CGPoint)arg3;
- (struct CGImage *)_imageMaskForPath:(struct CGPath *)arg1 anchorEdge:(unsigned long long)arg2 anchorPoint:(struct CGPoint)arg3;
- (struct CGPath *)_newMinimalAppearancePathInBounds:(struct CGRect)arg1 anchorEdge:(unsigned long long)arg2 anchorPoint:(struct CGPoint)arg3 topCapOnly:(BOOL)arg4 arrowOffset:(double)arg5;
- (struct CGPath *)_newMinimalAppearancePathInBounds:(struct CGRect)arg1 anchorEdge:(unsigned long long)arg2 arrowPosition:(double)arg3 topCapOnly:(BOOL)arg4 arrowOffset:(double)arg5;
- (void)_setHasDragWindowAppearance:(BOOL)arg1;
- (BOOL)_hasDragWindowAppearance;
- (void)_tileAndRedisplay:(BOOL)arg1;
- (struct CGRect)contentRectForFrameRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 styleMask:(unsigned long long)arg2;
- (struct CGRect)frameRectForContentRect:(struct CGRect)arg1 styleMask:(unsigned long long)arg2;
- (void)_setDragImage:(id)arg1;
- (id)_dragImage;
- (void)dealloc;
- (void)_windowTransformAnimationDidEnd:(id)arg1;
- (void)_windowTransformAnimationWillBegin:(id)arg1;
- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow;
- (void)_loadTheme;
- (void)viewWillDraw;
@property BOOL shouldBlurBackground;
- (void)_setWindowBackgroundBlurIfNeeded;
- (BOOL)_canHaveBlur;
- (void)_invalidateShadow;
@property BOOL shouldInsetForAnchor; // @dynamic shouldInsetForAnchor;
- (id)initWithCoder:(id)arg1;
- (id)initWithFrame:(struct CGRect)arg1 styleMask:(unsigned long long)arg2 owner:(id)arg3;
- (id)initWithFrame:(struct CGRect)arg1;
- (void)_commonPopoverInit;

@end
```

Then I could subclass `_NSPopoverWindow`, which is also private, and override

`+ (Class)frameViewClassForStyleMask:(unsigned long long)arg1;`

I can't subclass it because it's private..
Is there a way to bypass this?

Or are there any other ways?

Comment: You could do this with public API. For iPad, look into creating your own custom UIPopover and for iPhone/iPad, look into subclassing a UIView to appear how you need.

Comment: @Anton NSPopover is Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes, NSPopover is OS X. Guess I thought you were asking about iPad for some reason, so I suggested UIPopoverController :)

Comment: You could always write your own, or modify one of the many FOSS rewrites out there.  Apple's popovers were never meant to be styled like that (even with a custom view, you'd have to override the border drawing).  As much as I hate to say it (because I've been burned before), [TwUI](https://github.com/twitter/twui) has a pretty good, and customizable, popover API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this great repository on Github:

https://github.com/github/Rebel

Does exactly what I was looking for.